# Can user makes sharing folder in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, server, active-directory

I'm using Active Directory and belong to specified group. (Not an Administrator.)
I have made folder in my 'C:' and then trying to share to another group users.
But I can't. Just i can get the warning message that '~Access denied~. You did not make shared resources.'.
Is there way to take care of this problem? 
Thank you~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing of resources might have been blocked by your Administrator, either get your self added in power users group / asked them to share folder for you. 
If you have Administrator Access - login with that and try. other wise less privileged user can not share the resources.

Comment: Thank you for replying! But, I can't get Administrator group... Maybe this case is about group policy. I think i have nothing to do :<